# Xcode 4.2 detect internet connection

Tags: networking, xcode4.2, reachability

Is there any other method apart from the Reachability one to detect if there is an internet connection available?

I´m trying to do this:
If there is internet connection, populate a table view from a plist on a server.
If there isn´t internet connection, populate the same table view with a plist on the phone.

Also, can this methods be combined so they don´t duplicate data?
Can I populate a Table View from both a server and a file in my app and compare both results and if repeated show only once?

Answer (score 2):

The reachability classes are the most reliable way to handle detecting if a device has an active internet connection. As far as merging data from a local plist and a remote plist, you can retreive the data from the two in to two different `NSSet` objects then call `setByAddingObjectsFromSet:` to join them

```
NSSet *localData = [NSSet new];
//Do Something to populate this Set
NSSet *remoteData = [NSSet new];
//Do Something to populate this Set
NSArray *tableData = [[localData setByAddingObjectsFromSet:remoteData]allObjects];
```